# Git branches deleted

Tags: git, github, rebase, revert

I was having three branches `master`, `b1` and `b2`. I was working on branch `b2`. There was a common folder which was present in all branches. While deleting the folder I selected, delete from other branch also. This option deleted folder as well and other two branches(`master` and `b1`) from the git server. Anyone know how I can get back `master` and `b1` branch back?

Comment: just revert back to a state when the folder was present, then delete it as necessary and continue

Answer (score 0):

You can use git reflog to find the SHA1 of the last commit of the branch. From that point, you can recreate a branch using

git branch branchName

Answer (score 0):

The `git revert` command undoes a committed snapshot. But, instead of removing the commit from the project history, it figures out how to undo the changes introduced by the commit and appends a new commit with the resulting content. This prevents Git from losing history, which is important for the integrity of your revision history and for reliable collaboration.

Usage:

```
git revert <commit>
```

Generate a new commit that undoes all of the changes introduced in , then apply it to the current branch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My issue is resolved with git revert